# Get a value of specific address

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

In assembly function, I take an integer address as a parameter.

I want to get a value of this address and manipulate this value. For example

```
puld
std $451
```

I keep the address in $451

Now I want to reach the integer value of this address at $451.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're working with a 9S12 processor variant, and your code takes a value from stack and puts it in address $451. But that means you have the value stored at $451 in your register D.

If I understand you correctly, the value in D is an address again itself. If you need to reach the value stored at that address, I'd use the index registers, e.g. X.

I don't have the full ref manual at hand, put something in the sense of

```
pulx
stx $451
ldaa 0,X
```

would give you the byte in your accumulator. Of course, if you need the address in D as well, you'd have to add an instruction `ldd $451` but that shouldn't be a problem.